# How do I implement a table that contains different types of cells?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Here is what I am trying to do: I want to make a 2D array of cells. Each cell can contain either a number or a string. Then I want to pass that table to an expression parser which I made. I need the parser to be able to recognize whether the cell in the expression contains a number - which is fine - or a string - not good.

This is how I tried to do it: I created an abstract base class `CCell` and three derived classes. One derived is `CCellEmpty`, one is `CCellText` and the last one is `CCellNumber`.

The table is a 2D array of pointers to the base class. In the expression parser, I need to get the number from the Number class. The problem is that you can't access private members of derived classes via base class pointer. Well, in the base class I could create a virtual getter for the number. In the number class it would return the desired number, but I would also need to implement it for the Text class and Empty class. For both of them it would throw an exception.
Note: I know it could be done with `dynamic_cast` but I don't want to go that way.

Is this a good way to do it? I am new to C++, object oriented programming and polymorphism, so if there is a better way to design it I will be glad to hear it. I would like to do it the right way, not just so it would work somehow.

This the code I'm using now:

```
#include <string>

class NotTextException{};
class NotNumberException{};

class CCell
{
    public:
        virtual ~CCell ( void ){}
        virtual int    GetNumber    ( void ) const = 0;
        virtual std::string GetText ( void ) const = 0;
};

class CCellEmpty : public CCell
{
    public:
        virtual int GetNumber ( void ) const {
             throw NotNumberException();
        }
        virtual std::string GetText ( void ) const {
             throw NotTextException();
        }

};

class CCellText : public CCell
{
    public:
        CCellText  ( const std::string & text )
         : m_text(text)
         {}
        virtual int GetNumber ( void ) const {
             throw NotNumberException();
        }
        virtual std::string  GetText ( void ) const {
            return m_text;
        }

    private:
        std::string m_text;
};

class CCellNumber : public CCell
{
    public:
        CCellNumber  ( const int num );
        virtual int GetNumber ( void ) const {
             return m_number;
        }
        virtual std::string  GetText ( void ) const {
            throw NotTextException();
        }

    private:
        int m_number;
};
```

Comment: Learn the concept of paragraphs. Remember to have a bash at writing code. Have a bash at tutorial number 1 and attend the lectures,

Comment: @KarolyHorvath OK so I realized there were some mistakes in what I wrote the first time. I edited it and added code sample.

Comment: Use @<username> to notify those guys. Otherwise they won't notice. Unfortunately SO lets you notify only one person per comment. Chose wisely. ^^

Comment: "Each cell can contain either a number or a string." - so what's the point of having `CCellEmpty`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It can contain, but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 2):

#### Cell and board

> Is this a good way to do it? I am new to C++, object oriented programming and polymorphism, so if there is a better way to design it I will be glad to hear it.

Yes, there's a better way: you can use `boost::variant` to represent a cell object and apply a visitor to each cell, in conjunction with `boost::optional` to signal the absence of a cell object.

Your cell and board type would look like:

```
using cell = boost::variant<int, std::string>;
using board = std::array<boost::optional<cell>, 100>;
```

And in 2 lines of code you are done. At this point you simply have to write a generic visitor that tries to get an element of type `Element` and otherwise throws an exception of type `Except`:

```
template<typename Type, typename Except>
struct element_getter : boost::static_visitor<Type> {
    template<typename Other>
    Type operator()(Other const&) const { throw Except(); }

    Type operator()(Type const& x) const { return x; }
};
```

#### Usage

At this point you just have to apply the visitor to each cell with `boost::apply_visitor` depending on whether or not the cell contains an element.

An example of usage would be:

```
board b;
b[45] = 42;
b[78] = 108;
auto sum = std::accumulate(begin(b), end(b), 0, 
    [](int counter, boost::optional<cell> cell) { 
        return counter + 
            boost::apply_visitor(
                element_getter<int, not_number_error>(), 
                cell.get_value_or(0)
            );
    }
);
```

This code will count all the cells that contain a number, but throw an exception if a cell contains a string.

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d3a570604224838)

Comment: As OP is new to C++: is there a better solution than OP's without using boost?

Comment: I have no experience with boost yet, and as much as I would like to learn it and use it here, this is a school assignment and we are only allowed to use libraries installed on the image we were provided and boost is not there... So considering no boost is available, is my implementation alright?

Comment: @traceur Yes, your implementation is alright. You are using dynamic dispatching to get the values of objects that can be either of one type or the other at runtime. Without boost or `dynamic_cast`, I can't think of a better and simpler way to achieve this.